# printing multidimensional array PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xls

I am trying to print fields from DB on .xls excel as:

```
$sql="select * from bill ";

$result=mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $ARP=$row['ARP_name'] ;
    $nam=$row['student_name'] ;

    $doc=array("ARP name"=>array('ARPname'=>($ARP),'name'=>$nam));
}
$xls->addArray ( $doc );
```

but the printing result is just the last record from DB , I want all the records to be printing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your braces are wrong:

```
$doc=array("ARP name"=>array('ARPname'=>($ARP),'name'=>$nam));}
                                                              ^
```

The brace needs to be after this line:

```
$xls->addArray ( $doc );
```

So, the full code would be:

```
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $ARP=$row['ARP_name'] ;
    $nam=$row['student_name'] ;

    $doc=array("ARP name"=>array('ARPname'=>($ARP),'name'=>$nam));
    $xls->addArray ( $doc );
}
```

Comment: Can I add the feilds name just once ?

Answer (score 2):

Move your last line into your while loop:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $ARP=$row['ARP_name'] ;
    $nam=$row['student_name'] ;

    $doc=array("ARP name"=>array('ARPname'=>($ARP),'name'=>$nam));
    $xls->addArray ( $doc );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have the `$xls->addArray` call outside of your while loop, You need to move it inside:

```
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $ARP=$row['ARP_name'] ;
    $nam=$row['student_name'] ;

    $doc=array("ARP name"=>array('ARPname'=>($ARP),'name'=>$nam));
    $xls->addArray ( $doc );
}
```